# An example of a field extension which is not Galois.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K=\Bbb Z_p(U,V)$, the field of rational functions in two variables $U$ and $V$ over $\Bbb Z_p,$ be taken as the base field. Now consider the polynomial $f(X)=(X^p-U)(X^p-V) \in K[X].$ Then by Kronecker's theorem $\exists$ a field $L'$ such that $f(X)$ splits completely into linear factors in $L'[X].$ But that will imply $X^p-U$ and $X^p-V$ split completely into linear factors in $L'[X].$ Cosequently both these polynomials have a root in $L'.$ Let $u$ and $v$ be some zeros of $X^p-U$ and $X^p-V$ respectively. Then $u^p=U$ and $v^p=V.$ Now using the fact that $\text{Char}\ (L')=p$ we find that $$X^p-U=X^p-u^p=(X-u)^p.$$ So $u$ is the only zero of $X^p-U$ with multiplicity $p.$ Similarly we can show that $v$ is the only zero $X^p-V.$ Let $V_{L'} (f(X))$ the set of zeros of $f(X)$ in $L'.$ Then we have $$V_{L'} (f(X)) = \{u,v \}.$$

Let $L=K(u,v)$ be the smallest subfield of $L'$ containing $K,u$ and $v.$ Then we have $$V_L(f(X))=\{u,v \}.$$ Since both $U$ and $V$ are primes in $\Bbb Z_p(U,V)$ so both the polynomials $X^p-U$ and $X^p-V$ are irreducible in $K[X].$ So they cannot have any root inside $K.$ Therefore $u,v \notin K.$ Therefore the degree of extension $[L:K] > 1.$ Now let $G= \text {Gal}\ (L|K).$ Let $\sigma \in G.$ Since $X^p-U$ and $X^p-V$ are respectively the minimal polynomials of $u$ and $v$ over $K$ it follows that $\sigma (u) \in V_L(X^p-U) = \{u \}$ and $\sigma (v) \in V_L(X^p-V) = \{v \}.$ But this implies that $\sigma(u)=u$ and $\sigma(v)=v.$ Since $\sigma$ is completely determined by the pair $(\sigma(u),\sigma(v))=(u,v).$ It follows that $\sigma = \text{id}_L.$ This shows that $G$ is a trivial group i.e. $\#\ G=1 < [L:K].$ Hence $L$ is not a Galois extension of $K.$

Now my question is can we not show the non Galois extension just by taking $K=\Bbb Z_p(U), f(X)= X^p-U$ and $L=K(u)$? Then also I believe $L$ is not a Galois extension of $K.$ Right? But then what is necessity of adjoing two variables to $\Bbb Z_p$ to demonstrate an example of a non Galois extension as given in the lecture notes provided by our instructor?

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: There is no necessity to adjoin two indeterminates: one will do. These extensions are inseparable, and so cannot be Galois. You may also like to see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3390973/operatornamegalkt1-p-u1-p-kt-u-contains-only-identity-automo/3390990#3390990

Comment: There is no need to use two variables *to this end*. However, your teacher may be planning to continue with this example later on. For $K(U^{1/p},V^{1/p})/K$ is a standard example for a finite extension with infinitely many intermediate fields.

Comment: Don't be affraid to write $u = U^{1/p}$ as you showed there is only one $p$-th root in characteristic $p$. Any automorphism fixing $K$ must be trivial because the minimal polynomials have only one root (conversely when there are other roots we can find a non-trivial automorphism of the normal closure : this is how we prove the fixed field and Galois correspondence stuffs).

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen I agree with you. In the very next lecture he is planning to prove a theorem which states that " Any finite Galois extension $L|K$ is simple." Since in our example $L=K(u,v) = K \left (U^{\frac 1 p} , V^{\frac 1 p} \right)$ is not a simple extension of $K$ it can't be Galois extension. I think this might be the reason for giving this example. One may immediately recognize $L|K$ in the example provided is non Galois once he/she is aware of the theorem that our instructor is going to prove in his very next lecture.

Comment: Quite. That is an even more commonly seen property of this extension (that I should have arguably spotted first also).

Comment: Thank you so much @Jyrki Lahtonen sir for your valuable suggestion.